# Cross Entropy calculation question: calculated is different from Keras' output

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning

I wrote a simple code to test Keras cross entropy, but got different results from [this post](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/bonus/softmax-regression.ipynb). I checked everything, but still do not know why keras gives me `1.1332054138183594`, but according to the post the correct number is `1.32159787159` (at [12] cell). Could anyone tell me why? I believe it is a math question on softmax and cross entropy instead of a coding question. That is why I ask here.

My code

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.utils import to_categorical
    import numpy as np

    np.random.seed(0)

    X = np.array([[0.1, 0.5], [1.1, 2.3], [-1.1, -2.3], [-1.5, -2.5]])
    y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2])

    y_enc = to_categorical(y)

    W = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]])

    b = np.array([0.01, 0.1, 0.1])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(3, weights=[W,b] , input_dim=2))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam')
    print(model.evaluate(X , y_enc))

    #1.1332054138183594
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the softmax activation

```
model.add(keras.layers.Softmax())
```

Comment: does cross entropy includes softmax?

Comment: @hxd1011 if you read the source code, no it does not, unless you specify the kwarg `from_logits` to be `True`, which is not the default setting.

Comment: could you give me a link to the source? I searched on github but did not find that part.

Comment: Also, i think the term "multi-class logistic loss" or cross entropy or softmax is loosely defined. I always get confused.

Comment: It is defined [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py#L68) which references this implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3461)